# Filter users by a custom field?

Tags: plugin-development, users, plugins

From within a plugin, I’m trying to filter users by a custom field.

An external post request will supply a variable which I want to match the custom field to. I then want to respond to that request with other user custom fields as JSON.

For example the incoming post contains customHandle1=A, I then find all the users where customHandle1=A and return customHandle2 and customHandle3 data.

How would I do that?

Comment: OK, just saw your question edit... will answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get a user by a custom field, you would need to create a ElementCriteriaModel like this:

```
$criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::User);
$criteria->fieldName = craft()->request->getPost('fieldName');

$users = $criteria->find();
```

you could then loop over $users and use getAttributes() to get the user data, and if you need the attribute names use attributeNames() if you need the users fields.

Comment: Hi Luke, how would you do this in Craft 3? :)

Comment: See https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/element-queries.html

Comment: Just a heads up, the element query page of the craft v3 docs doesn't actually help. If you create an element query and then try to search by a custom field it will absolutely fail as it's expecting it to be a 'real' field. The docs surrounding this in v3 really don't help at all. A simple thing like searching for users by a custom field is seemingly impossible.